# Get Image from Database with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get an image from my database I use the following code:

```
  <?php   
    $image_qry=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM Benutzer");
    $image=mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_qry);
    $get_image=$image['Profilbild']; //This should contain the picture
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
    echo $get_image;
     ?>
```

Here is my database structure:

[image: Users]

Please help me and tell me how can i output this picture in a commun `<div>` element

Comment: move header() to top of script and test again

Comment: what error do you get.

Comment: @meh because there was no output before the echo, placing the `header()` anywhere else has no extra function... Check if the image is actually in the database ... should be a BLOB field that can hold the image... A regular BLOB field is 65k, so if the image were larger than that, you don't have an image

Comment: @Raphioly-San you're right but it's not the complete script he might echoed header.html in another include somewhere. _PS: the size is 53.3_

Comment: Use `echo mysqli_error($mysqli);` to check if the query gave errors...

Comment: Okay, now i have an output, but this is a huge string.... starting with a lot of\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0

Comment: A very BADDD and horrible technique to store images in DB :)

Comment: NEVER EVER store images into DB ... store image names into DB and then save image into a directory on your server ....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing your image inside of the database create a upload folder then just store the image name into the database and when you want to call it just add the name at the end.

```
<?php   
    $image_qry=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM Benutzer");
    $image=mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_qry);

    $link = directory of image;
    $get_image=$link.$image; //This should contain the picture

    echo file_get_contents($get_image);
?>
```

upload script:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```

reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: You are correct, that should be done as 'the better way', but that was not the question

Comment: and how can i save my picture in that folder?

Comment: create a upload script which will upload the pictures, if you want i can include on in the post

Comment: @LaurinZiegler already one there, if this helped u dont forget to press the tick :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the array of results you got contain the first row in index 0

```
$get_image=$image[0]['Profilbild'];
```